# Post closed as (whatever) by *everyone*?

Tags: bug, closing

I recently cast a fifth and final close vote. I voted to close as "unclear", but the other four went for "too broad". Although I do not disagree that the post was too broad, I am slightly miffed that the implication is there.

In the past the boiler-plate$^{\dagger}$ comment was "signed" by those who agreed (which dispenses with the above issue), so here it would have four signatures. However, it has none, and searching around I see that this is not isolated:

> Boiler-plate comments have no signatures anymore. What has happened?

---

$^{\dagger}$ By a "boiler-plate comment" I mean the works after the close reason which are posted when a question is closed. For "too broad" is reads as follows.

> *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: Were those ever shown, except for the reasons in the "off-topic" group? I don't remember.

Comment: I cannot remember either. If so, then my question will miraculously morph into a feature request...

Comment: I think you can make it a feature request, though it's a repeat of [this ancient request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/).  Old closed questions [like this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/568886/147263) don't have the signatures, and I know that the text of close notices remains as it was, even if the close reason does not exist anymore. (One can also check with Wayback Machine, but I don't feel like it.)

Comment: [What do you mean "everyone"?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74BzSTQCl_c)

Comment: I meant `*everyone*` as in *everyone*! (The five people who voted to close.)